# GTK+: Showing a label when mouse is hovering on a button

Tags: gtk

I have a button that is displayed with an image.

I would like to show some text when the mouse is hovering on top of it (like any desktop icon would do, or even images on HTML pages).

I am not sure if there is any facility to do that, I could not find any by looking at the GtkButton class.

Does anyone please know how I can set some text labels when the mouse is hovering on top of a button please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`GtkTooltip`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTooltip.html). There are simple APIs as part of `GtkWidget` to set & get tool tip. Use [`gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-tooltip-text) to add simple text as tips for the widget or [`gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-tooltip-markup) for adding text with [Pango markup language](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html). Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(void)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *button0;
    GtkWidget *button1;

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    button0 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Normal tip");
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button0, "Simple tip");

    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Markup tip");
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup(button1, "This is <b>bold</b> &amp; this is <i>italics</i>");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), button0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), button1, 1, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!